# kafka-net SendAsync not timing out

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am using kafka-net sdk for producing and consuming kafka messages. Able to produce and consume the message when Kafka Provider is available.

But, On unavailablity of kafka, SendAsync (of KafkaConnection method) is not timing out even after the response is timed out. It is waiting indefinitely at this point.

How to breakout or get timeout exception after the response timeout has happened?

Comment: Hi @Jayakrishna, if possible can you please share your sample application? I'm new to kafka so would like to see the implementation to understand kafka.